# MFC: limit the size of child control from the code of control itself

Tags: winapi, mfc

Say, I have a CListCtrl-derived control. I want it to be always square (i.e. it's width and height should be always equal to each other).

The control resides on a dialog (CDialog-based), it is resized once the dialog is resized (the control is resized using SetWindowPos()). What I want to achieve is to make it impossible to resize the control improperly: the control must always have equal horizontal and vertical dimensions regardless of what is passed to SetWindowPos.

Of course, I can control the values that are passed to SetWindowPos. The question is: is it possible to control the size of the CListCtrl-derived control inside the code of that control itself?

Comment: In MFC, go to resource editor, right click on the control. The property section will show "Dynamic Layout". Set "sizing type" to "both". This will proportionally resize the child control when the main dialog is resized.

Comment: Why not simply call `SetWindowPos()` with the appropriate values in first place?

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani: it won't do the trick, the control may be square initially but then it will become rectangular during the resizing process (whether it's proportional or not) as the monitor screen is not square.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I want the control to be able to prevent itself from being non-square, that's just the task as it is. I've specifically mentioned that I can pre-process the values for SetWindowPos(), there would be no question if that could have done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you subclass the control and have it handle the [`WM_SIZING` message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-sizing) you can constrain the resize in any way you'd like. Just modify the `RECT` structure that's passed with the message.

Comment: Nice hint, I could achieve what I needed via WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING handling though... for some reason, my control does not receive WM_SIZING. Why WM_SIZING may not come to a control?

Comment: @Roman thanks for the feedback. Possibly you only get `WM_SIZING` when the window is being dragged by the edges. In your case it's being controlled apparently by the parent dialog?

Comment: The size of the control is changed via explicit SetWindowPos() calls that occur from parent dialog's WM_SIZE handler. So yes, the size of the control is not changed in a 'natural' way of dragging edges.